How to implement push notification for windows flutter app?
I'm trying to implement push notification on windows flutter apps but could not  find any plugin for it.
I've used firebase_messaging plugin to get fcmToken for other platforms like android, iOS, MacOS and web but it doesn't support windows platform but I need to implement this on windows as well.

Future<String?> getFcmToken() async {
    try {
      String? token;
      if (kIsWeb || Platform.isAndroid || Platform.isIOS || Platform.isMacOS) {
        token = await firebaseMessaging.getToken();
      }else if (Platform.isWindows) {
        token = '';
      }
     
      debugPrint("FCM TOKEN--------------->$token");
      return token;
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint("FCM TOken error ----------->$e");
      rethrow;
    }
  }


If you're trying to receive push notifications on Windows through FCM, that is simply not supported (as far as I know).

Check out this package on pub : windows_notification
This package will allow you to send notifications with text, small or large images. It even allows you to clear notification history.

I did but it has required param called as applicationId which i'm not able to understand what applicationId it need....?
and I think, this is for local notification not for push notification.

The package documentation gives a default appId; I think you should use that only. The appId given there belongs to FOLDERID_SystemX86. Tell me if that doesn't work
